How to use the すぎ suffix to mean "too much"?
I'm kind of confused as to how to use すぎ as a suffix to a verb to mean "do something too much"
Part of the confusion stems from the fact that (from what I see), we suffix すぎ to the "root" of the verb, i.e. 食べすぎ instead of, say, 食べるすぎ.
In that case, how do I say things like:

will not eat too much (食べすぎません? 食べませんすぎ?)
ate too much (食べすぎました? 食べましたすぎ?)
did not eat too much (食べすぎませんでした? 食べませんでしたすぎ?)
do not eat too much (食べすぎて? 食べてすぎ?)
let's not eat too much (食べすぎましょう? 食べましょうすぎ?)


The entire suffix is ～すぎる which is a "ru" verb.  Using it as just ～すぎ is simply a noun usage.
Your understanding of the formation is correct—you attach it to the "root" of the verb.  But now all your conjugations happen on ～すぎる, not on the root verb.  So you get:

will not eat too much - 食べ[すぎません]{LLLLL}・食べ[すぎない]{LLLL}
ate too much - 食べ[すぎました]{LLLLL}・食べ[すぎた]{LLL}
did not eat too much - 食べ[すぎませんでした]{LLLLLLLL}・食べ[すぎなかった]{LLLLLL}
do not eat too much - 食べ[すぎるな]{LLLL}・食べ[すぎないで]{LLLLL}
let's not eat too much - 食べ[すぎない]{LLLL}ようにしよう・食べ[すぎ(る)まい]{LLLLLLL} (?) (This is kind of an odd thing to say).


As a side note, you may also use すぎる with い-adjectives and な-adjectives, just drop the い・な and attach すぎる. E.g. 静かな→静かすぎる　遠い→遠すぎる

@dvx2718:  Yes, thank you.  I don't know why I didn't think to add that.

Oh, from what I see above, when you attach すぎる to a verb, it becomes a 一段 verb and follow that conjugation pattern? So if I want to say "do not swim too much", it would now be 泳すぎない (instead of 泳すぎがない) even though "swim" (泳ぐ) is originally a 五段 (ぐ) verb?

@PieFaced:  泳[ぎ]{L}すぎない

Oh! Then actually my understanding has been incorrect! (On hindsight, 食べる wasn't the best example, being a 一段 verb...). So it should be: 泳ぐ --> 泳ぎすぎる, 飲む --> 飲みすぎる, 書く --> 書きすぎる, 取る --> 取りすぎる, etc... and that all the "... すぎる's" are 一段 verbs, right?

Yes, that is correct.
